# Error al tratar de genera Apk en Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

```
Unzipping /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip to /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9

Exception in thread "main" 
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
(node:5814) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /home/joel/Documentos/Menu_lateral/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

no se de donde sale esto y porque. ni como solucionarlo

Comment: ¿Utilizaste "sudo" adelante del comando?

Comment: use este "ionic cordova build android --prod --release" . donde deberia poner ese sudo???

Comment: sudo ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Comment: con eso, ejecutas como administrador

Comment: pero ese comando lo ejecuto en modo root.. Sudo es diferente??

Comment: negativo, es lo mismo. Te sugiero instalar el Android Studio para que le ponga todas las dependencias que se necesiten